# ExtJS4 Tree store is loading twice

Tags: extjs4

I am having a problem with the ExtJS4 `TreeStore`. Even though `autoLoad` set to false, the store is getting loaded twice.

In my case I am using `JSON` reader to parse the `JSON` response and `rootVisible` is set to false in the view class.

My TreeStore code is:

```
Ext.define('xxx.HostHierarchy', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    autoLoad: false,

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: '/xxx/hostsview.json'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            totalProperty: 'total',
            successProperty: 'success',
            root: 'data'
        }
    }
});
```

After some search & debug, I found out that if `rootVisible` property set to `false`, then expanded property of root will be set to true which triggers multiple requests.

To avoid this I added

```
setRootNode: function(node) {
    var me = this;
    if (node != undefined) {
        node.expanded = false;
    }
},
```

But its not working.

Can somebody please suggest me how to avoid this. Because of this multiple load, on my UI screen all tree nodes are appearing twice.

ExtJS version is 4.0.5.

Thanks and Regards,

Nari

Comment: Most likely this is caused by the nodes returned in your JSON not have `loaded` set to true. I would able to confirm this if you share both the returned json and your model definition.

Comment: also, upgrade to 4.1.1 - lots of bug fixes including trees.

Comment: can i see the JSON result?
have u use 'leaf' in the JSON?
set 'leaf:false' if the data have children
and set 'leaf:true' if the data haven't children